# How could I make Bootstrap table with sticky table head?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a (responsive) Bootstrap table. I would like the table head to scroll along when scrolling down the table data. I do not wish to set a height for the table as I would like the page to grow when adding more rows. So simply setting a height and `overflow-y: scroll` will not suffice.

Setting a `position: fixed` or even `position: sticky` will not solve my problem either.

This is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/qaxczt8u/) I tried:

```css
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

thead {
  /* position: fixed; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there not anything that Bootstrap offers to support such feature (fixed/sticky table header)?

Comment: This question is being answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001954/css-only-sticky-table-headers-in-chrome)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42507340/9564225) might help you.

Comment: @MohdTabishBaig This has helped me out. Will post the solution in an answer.

Comment: i have added the solution, please check and accept it as an answer, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nw940duo/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already answered this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56668384/9380480).
You can do this way by setting `position: sticky;`

```css
table thead tr th {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
      <th>column3</th>
      <th>column4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason I should be using `z-index` here?

Comment: Edited that. Not necessary. It depends on the way you structure your layout

Comment: Would you be able to tell me if I could apply the following solution to a [table](https://jsfiddle.net/cuxhdk69/) with multiple rows within the table head as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your css:

```
table thead tr:first-child th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Mohd Tabish Baig's comment I figured out that apparently I had to dig a bit deeper into the target element. Instead of adding `position: sticky` to `thead`, I had to add it more specifically to its children `th`'s. The following fiddle shows a solution that helped me out:

```css
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to set `top:-1px` as you can see the gap  when you scroll. You can see that in my answer