# how to make table head fixed while using navbar in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have a navbar and a table. The table is long and wide so it needs to be scrollable both and x and y.

I have seen other answer on stackoverflow but I am not able to do the same for my website.

I am not sure even if the custom CSS is being used properly.
The table is taken from examples I found on the web. The nav header is working properly and stays on top. But the Table header does not and it disappears when I scroll down.

```css
table thead tr th {
  background-color: white !important;
  position: sticky !important;
  top: -1px !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/empdetails/custom.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>EmpDetails</title>
  <script>
    // some custom scripts
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EmpDetails</a>
    <form class="form-inline" action="javascript:update();">
      <input class="form-control mx-3 ml-4" type="search" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Employee Name" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success bg-success  mx-3 text-light" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info bg-info  mx-3 text-light" onclick="download();">Download</button>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="table" class="table table-hover">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>column1</th>
          <th>column2</th>
          <th>column3</th>
          <th>column4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
          <td>td</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/empdetails/custom.css" />

</body>

</html>
```

I tried a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804484/how-could-i-make-bootstrap-table-with-sticky-table-head) I think I am not doing it properly. Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a fixed position on table head element like this:

```
thead {
  position: fixed;
}
```

This should keep your columns fixed on top

Comment: cool. I can fix the header to be on top and align it with top:62px. The column width are not matching the tbody. Any idea how I can match them.